# Select only defined column in LINQ

Tags: c#, mysql, linq

I am writing a simple `LINQ` query. Table structure is defined below:

**Table A**

```
Id int,
VName varchar2(20),
VAddress varchar2(200)
```

**Table B**

```
Id int,
NName varchar2(20),
NAddress varchar2(200)
```

`LINQ` Query

```
 from c in A 
  join x in B on c.Id equals x.Id
     order by A.Id 
     select New{
            c.Id,
            x.NName
     }
```

Then SQL Generate as

```
  select Filter1.Id,Filter1.NName from(
    Select Extend1.Id,Extend1.VName,Extend1.VAddress,
           Extend2.Id as Id1,Extend2.NName,Extend2.NAddress
      from A as Extend1 Inner Join B as Extend2 on Extend1.Id=Extend2.ID)
   as Filter1
```

**MY Problem:** I don't want select many columns in SubQuery.

Comment: Database engine is smart enough to figure out you don't need these columns anyway and they will not affect your query performance at all.

Comment: It is affect on my query performace, thats I was post this here

Comment: How did you test that?

Comment: I was use DB Profile to analyze the query performance

Answer (score 0):

If you're *really* worried about performance, then just use plain `SQL`... it's just about always faster than `Linq` (in my personal experience). Also, you can try using this `Linq` to execute your `SQL`:

```
IEnumerable<YourDataType> result = DataContext.ExecuteQuery<YourDataType>(SqlString);
```

You can find out more from the [`DataContext.ExecuteQuery<TResult> Method (String, Object\[\])`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb361109.aspx) page at MSDN. Please note that this page relates to a different overload of this method, but it has examples in it.

Comment: Dear @Sheridan: I know `Simple SQL` is faster then `LINQ` but my question is How can be write as asked in my question. Is it possible or not.

Comment: As far as I am aware, we have no direct control over the way that `Linq` generates its queries. If you're *really* worried about performance, then just use the above example to feed your own `SQL query` into the `Linq` system.